# directory mapping with cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

Anyone know when in CloudBees I can do a directory mapping? Tomcat does

```
<Context path="/abc" docBase="/a/b/c" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without hacking the related tomcat clickstack to customize container. Anyway, why no just have such static resources under /abc ?

Comment: That is what I have gone with, but it means every time the core is updated the directory will have to be copied again

Comment: PaaS deployment anyway is based on full application deployment (on platform, SDK from developer's laptop can do delta deploys), so that same app can be (re)deployed on another cluster's node : a redeploy/restart means a fresh new server run your app, vs traditional hosting to provide a fixed server for your app

Comment: you can use a CDN and then change links to point to the CDN if you like (is good for assets that are loaded).